# How to count the number of CRTP subclasses of a template class?

Tags: c++, counter, template-meta-programming, crtp, subclass

Does anyone know of a method to use CRTP to count the number of subclasses of an object?

Suppose we had a setup similar to the following one:

```
template <typename T>    
class Object
{
    ....  
};

const unsigned int ObjectSubClassCount = ...; 

class Subobject : public Object<SubObject>
{
    ....
};

class Second : public Object<Second>
{
    ....
};
```

and so on, such that, using TMP, we might have a constant (`ObjectSubClassCount`) that represents the total number of subclasses?

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Edit: I am wanting to use the result as a template parameter later on, so I need it to be done with TMP...

Comment: Just to note, I am working to solve this problem, myself.  Just asking you guys in case I never do, or you do it first.

Comment: Should be possible - do you want to have a counter for the subclasses at every hierarchy level or just the whole number of subclasses of object?

Comment: Just the subclasses at that level;  Not expecting a heirarchy.

Comment: Why are you relating CRTP with your question? It may not have anything to do with it. Edited your question. You want to find number of subclasses for a given `template` class? I doubt if it will be possible.

Comment: Optimally, I want the subclasses to be ignorant of eachother, as well.  Optimally, but optionally.

Comment: possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/8596490/819272

Comment: @iammilind The CRTP is probably because of the related trick of counting *object* instances of a given class, see e.g. http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31473&seqNum=3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the requirement to use the result as a template parameter later I would try it doing like this:

```
// Class which increments a given counter at instanciation
struct Increment {
  Increment(std::size_t& counter)
  {
    counter++;
  }
};

// This is your template base
template <typename T>    
class Object
{
  private:
    // For every instanciation of the template (which is done for a subclass)
    // the class counter should get incremented
    static Increment incrementCounter;
};

// This is the global object counter
static std::size_t classCounter;

// Static Member Variable
template<typename T>
Object<T>::incrementCounter(classCounter);
```

Haven't tried it but should do. To have the result available as a template parameter again (MPL) I don't have enough experience in MPL but I doubt this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've come upon a... somewhat acceptable answer.
I figured that it would not work out if the subclasses had absolutely not knowledge of eachother (I mean, we're talking somewhat functional programming...).

Here's a solution for this.  It's definitely not the solution I'd wish for; however, it is a start.  I've forced all objects to use a form of CRTP, but one that uses more of a linked list format.  In this way, our subclasses must be derived from an Object<> templated from:

A: itself
and B: the most recent previously defined subclass

here is my code for this (I use a template from `<type_traits>` once, just a note)

```
template <typename T>   //SFINAE check for the existance of subclasscount static member
struct has_subclasscount
{

    template <typename U>
    static typename std::enable_if<sizeof(U::subclasscount) != 0, int>::type test(int);

    template <typename U>
    static char test(...);

    static const bool result = (sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(int))?(true):(false);
};


template <bool res, typename T>
struct return_subclasscount //the value to return is 0 if false
{
    static const int result = 0;
};


template <typename T>       
struct return_subclasscount<true, T>    //returns subclasscount only if the first parameter is true
{
    static const int result = T::subclasscount;
};


template <typename T>               //combines return_subclasscount and has_subclasscount
struct get_subclasscount
{
    static const int result = return_subclasscount<has_subclasscount<T>::result, T>::result;
};


template <typename This, typename Prev>
class Object
{
public:

    static const int subclasscount = 1 + get_subclasscount<Prev>::result;   //the subclass count
};


class sub1 : public Object<sub1, int>
{

};


class sub2 : public Object<sub2, sub1>
{

};


class sub3 : public Object<sub3, sub2>
{

};
```

These last 3 empty classes are the subclasses that we're counting.  This is our header file.
In our main .cpp file, we have:

```
int main() {

std::cout << sub3::subclasscount;

char c;
std::cin >> c;
}
```

Running it, we get a simple output of:

> 3

Which confirms that it has worked.
Now, some of the downsides to this solution is:

- We must know what our last defined subclass was, before we add on.
- We must keep up with anywhere we use the subclass counter, always modifying it to be from the last subclass in the list (this can be averted by using a consistant "endoflist" subclass, which would need to be maintained instead)

Upsides, though, include the fact that we do not need to upkeep any of our previously defined subclasses.  However, I consider this answer more of a "starting point" than a "final solution"; perhaps something that can be expanded upon?

(also, this can easily be abused to make a form of tree structure, where `subclasscount` would actually represent the depth of any given node in the tree)

Anyone have any ideas from here?